# "Add New Item" templates are missing from VS 2019 (v16.10.4)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

I have recently installed VS 2019 Community on a new machine. I've noticed that some Project Templates and almost all Item Templates are missing. These modules are installed:
[image: Visual Studio Installer configuration]

When I go to the Solution Explorer, right-click "Add>New Item" the dialogue is missing most of the Templates that I'm used to seeing:
[image: Normally many more options here]

I use mostly C# and have installed Xamarin, but cannot add any Xamarin Forms, as they are missing. Despite the fact that I have installed Xamarin, apparently correctly.
[image]

In poking around on the internet, I found a [POST](https://kwilson.io/blog/fix-visual-studio-when-templates-disappear-from-your-add-new-item-dialogue/) that mentioned two folders within the Visual Studio installation folders. The Cache folders are entirely absent in my installation, and there are no .zip files in the Templates folders. I manually added the Cache folders and ran the command as noted without any change. Nothing appeared in the Cache folders.

Any help would be VERY appreciated. Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following methods:

1.try to repair you visual studio first.

For more details, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

2.If the problem persists, try to perform a thorough uninstall for Xamarin for Visual Studio.

For more details, check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/uninstall-xamarin-vs

Comment: Thank you, Jessie, though I just completed both updating to v16.11.0 and Repairing (which had me restart my computer) and neither worked. Still no templates. I've uninstalled Xamarin several times to no effect as well.

Comment: Have you performed a thorough uninstall for your visual studio ,just as the second advice mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I did, I believe that did it, there was also an update that occurred yesterday. Either way, I can add Xamarin forms now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If VS is updated to last version, and the problem still exists, In Visual Studio Installer Click on modify, in WorkLoads tab, make sure all items required in your project are checked. if not, check them and modify it.